# Can life subsist on anything else but water?

Tags: astrobiology, speculative

Inspired by an [answer to a previous question.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8972/why-must-a-planet-be-in-a-stars-habitable-zone-to-have-life)

It's hypothesized that extraterrestrial life could be based on silicon rather than carbon as its main structural element.

Are there similar theories about an alternative "life solvent" rather than water?

Comment: Ha, I was just about to ask the very same thing having read the same question!

Comment: Some scientists are indeed working toward inorganic life [see here, bottom part](http://www.reportergene.com/2011/11/trends-in-synthetic-biology-2011.html). Not that they succeeded yet, but it's an active research field.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a definitive answer.

The solvent closest to water in its properties such as dielectric constant, melting/boiling points, etc are formamide and sulphuric acid.

```
                        F       S       W
Melting point (⁰C)      2       10      0
Boiling point (⁰C)      210     337     100
Dielectric Const        109     84–100  80
Specific gravity        1.133   1.94    1
```

But water is the simplest i.e made up of only two types of atoms (Which are decently abundant).

Regarding silicon: even though silicon can undergo some level of catenation (silanes) it is not comparable to carbon. Silicon can form polymers like silicone (poly-siloxanes). But I think carbon seems to be more versatile. It is also more abundant (check [this](http://www.periodictable.com/Properties/A/UniverseAbundance.html) out. A nice representation of abundance of different elements in the universe)

Also check [this](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/340/6132/577.full) out: it is about exoplanet habitability.

Since certain elements are more abundant than others, the likelihood of them giving rise to life is higher. Therefore water seemingly emerges as the life solvent.

[*still most times we see everything in an earth point of view*]

Answer (score 5):

This may not completely answer your question, but provide some information.

Looking at this Wikipedia outline [Non water solvents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry#Non-water_solvents), other possible candidates are ammonia, hydrocarbons even hydrogen fluoride.

Digging a little deeper, [this abstract of the article: "Many chemistries could be used to build living systems."](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15253836) (Abstract only) describes the possibilities of ammonia and liquid nitrogen as being potential suitable solvents.  Page 678 onwards of the article: ["Is there a common chemical model for life in the universe?"](http://westheimerinstitute.org/pubs/Is%20there%20a%20common%20chemical%20model%20for%20life%20in%20the%20universe?.pdf) also describes other solvents such as ammonia (I should say that there quite a lot of Star Trek references in that paper).

I hope this goes part of the way to help.